# XML to XML Mapping XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

Im trying to map an XML to XML format via XSLT. My Code works well when using the XSL transform in Studio but when attached to an outbound EIB, some fields dont work specifically when multiple xpaths.

**Here is the XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Job_Requisition_Details">
<wd:Report_Entry>

<wd:Job_ID>12345</wd:Job_ID>

<wd:Job_Title>Associate Manager, Packaging Engineer</wd:Job_Title>

<wd:Time_Type wd:Descriptor="Full time">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">c6ae74e96c9c45569afea6b4c1bb5ca5</wd:ID>
<wd:ID wd:type="Position_Time_Type_ID">Full_time</wd:ID>
</wd:Time_Type>

</wd:Report_Entry>

</wd:Report_Data>
```

**Here is my Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Job_Requisition_Details" version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- TODO: Auto-generated template -->
        
        <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
            <wd:Job_ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Job_ID"/>
            </wd:Job_ID>
            <wd:Job_Title>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Job_Title"></xsl:value-of>
            </wd:Job_Title>
            <wd:Time_Type>
                <xsl:for-each select="wd:Time_Type">
                    <wd:Descriptor>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@wd:Descriptor"></xsl:value-of>
                    </wd:Descriptor>
                    <wd:WID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:ID[@wd:type = 'WID']"></xsl:value-of>
                    </wd:WID>                    
                    <wd:Position_Time_Type>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Position_Time_Type_ID']"></xsl:value-of>
                    </wd:Position_Time_Type>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </wd:Time_Type>                

        </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Here is the output after attaching to outbound EIB:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
      xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Job_Requisition_Details">
   <wd:Job_ID>12345</wd:Job_ID>
   <wd:Job_Title>Associate Manager, Packaging Engineer</wd:Job_Title>
   <wd:Time_Type>
      </wd:Descriptor>
      </wd:WID>
      </wd:Position_Time_Type>
   </wd:Time_Type>
</body>
```

**Required output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
      xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Job_Requisition_Details">
   <wd:Job_ID>12345</wd:Job_ID>
   <wd:Job_Title>Associate Manager, Packaging Engineer</wd:Job_Title>
   <wd:Time_Type>
      <wd:Descriptor>Full time</wd:Descriptor>
      <wd:WID>c6ae74e96c9c45569afea6b4c1bb5ca5</wd:WID>
      <wd:Position_Time_Type>Full_time</wd:Position_Time_Type>
   </wd:Time_Type>
</body>
```

---

Kindly help, I also tried different declarations but still does not work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your script is working perfect: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZz